how do I get CPU architecture without using the filesystem (/proc/cpuinfo or lscpu)?
I just discovered, that I get wrong information for the cpu-arch on a board with a rasperrby pi compute module 3+ (Broadcom BCM2837B0, Cortex-A53 (ARMv8) 64-bit SoC @ 1.2GHz)
# lscpu
Architecture:        armv7l
...

# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)

# dmesg | grep -i cpu
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fd034] revision 4 (ARMv7), cr=10c5383d

# uname -m
armv7l

I think I messed this up when migrating an old image from CM1 to CM3.
lscpu seems to just look into the FS to get the CPU-arch.
So, I wonder if there is a way to realistically get the CPU-arch directly from the CPU?

Did you try the Raspberry PI SE site -> [raspberrypi.se]?

@phuzi this just happens to be a rapsberry pi, but its not really a raspberry pi question. more about the inner workings of tools like lscpu.

Your assumption is incorrect. The /proc directory represents a pseudo filesystem that is not stored anywhere. The information for the pseudo file cpuinfo would be generated on the fly by accessing hardware. Did you boot a 32-bit kernel on a 64-bit system? Then don't expect the 32-bit code to properly identify a 64-bit CPU. See linux/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c

This blog post on the ARM users community may do what you want runtime detection of ARM features. Untested.

that makes sense, as it is a 32bit OS on a 64bit arch. But still, why does Line 1312 seq_printf(m, "CPU architecture: %s\n",proc_arch[cpu_architecture()]); output "7" (should be "8")

@MartinBrown the blog describes exactly my problem, and hwcaps seems a good fit, but its not available for my (old) kernel.

"But still, why ..." - Because the ARMv8 processor has to run in AArch32 state (which is compatible with the ARMv7-A architecture) in order to execute the 32-bit kernel. In effect the ARMv8 processor is emulating a ARMv7-A processor and the 32-bit kernel sees a known HW environment. Ref: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100961/1101-00/Introduction/ARMv8-64-bit-architecture-overview
